# Removing the label within a Hyperlink leaving only the hyperlink as a text

Tags: excel-formula

I have created a column with rows of different hyperlinks a hyperlink within a cell, with a link label attached . Now i want to display only the hyperlink(as a text)and remove the label for each row within the column. Is this possible with a formula? I don't want to have to remove them manually one at a time

Answer (score 0):

It is easily done in VBA.
Press Alt+F11 (this will open the VBA editor)
Insert a new module.
Copy this in to the module:

```
    Function GetHyperlink(Rng As Range)
    GetHyperlink = Rng.Hyperlinks(1).Address
End Function
```

*(This will add a new custom function, which is a formula that extracts hyperlink from cell)*

Then if you go back to your workbook, enter a formula where you want to extract the hyperlink. 
Your formula will be =GetHyperlink(A1) 
Assuming your hyperlinked cell is in A1.

Let me know if it works.